# How to have two router-outlets in Angular app component?

Tags: angular

What I am going to achieve is to load my sign-in component without any sidebar and top bar.

Here is a simple version of my app component and what I have tried so far:

`app.component.html`: (simple version)

```
<div>
   <div id="side-bar">sidebar goes here</div>
   <div id="top-bar">top bar goes here</div>
   <div id="content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </div>
</div>
<router-outlet name="sign-in-outlet"></router-outlet>
```

`app-routing.module.ts`: (simple version)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'auth' },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('@my-project/auth').then(m => m.AuthModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('@my-project/dashboard').then(
        m => m.DashboardModule
      )
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

`auth.module.ts`: (simple version)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent, outlet: 'sign-in-outlet' }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    SignInComponent
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

When I go to the `localhost:4200/auth/sign-in` url, then I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'auth/sign-in'

Comment: Is your question about `How to have 2 router-oulets in angular component` or are you asking why you get the described error with your routing config?

Comment: @MikeS., my intention is to have two router-outlets in app component and load the sign-in component out of layout as described above.

Comment: You can use one router-outlet and on other routes you can have parent page who has sidebar and all and then there you can define router-outlet

Comment: @MustafaKunwa, your comment is not clear to me at all.

Comment: try checking this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-nested-routing?file=src/app/about/about.component.html

Comment: @MustafaKunwa, in your example when I go to the about page again I see the main layout. I do not want to see the main layout when I go to my sign-in view.

Comment: Check the About page properly it has a children's route, and that is how you have to do it. An example is just a reference for you just check it deeply you will understand how to use it